# Android alarm Clock

Tags: android, clock, android-alarms

Hello i have the problem.

LogCat giving me some errors.

LogCat:

```
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(DateFormat.java:204)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.Alarms.get24HourMode(Alarms.java:536)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.DigitalClock.setDateFormat(DigitalClock.java:192)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.DigitalClock.onFinishInflate(DigitalClock.java:121)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock$AlarmTimeAdapter.newView(AlarmClock.java:96)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:182)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

A bit of code ( where there are errors )

LogCat:

```
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.Alarms.get24HourMode(Alarms.java:536)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.DigitalClock.setDateFormat(DigitalClock.java:192)
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.DigitalClock.onFinishInflate(DigitalClock.java:121)
```

Code:

```
static Calendar calculateAlarm(int hour, int minute, Alarm.DaysOfWeek daysOfWeek) {

    // start with now
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

int nowHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int nowMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// if alarm is behind current time, advance one day
if (hour < nowHour  ||
    hour == nowHour && minute <= nowMinute) {
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

int addDays = daysOfWeek.getNextAlarm(c);
/* Log.v("** TIMES * " + c.getTimeInMillis() + " hour " + hour +
   " minute " + minute + " dow " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + " from now " +
   addDays); */
if (addDays > 0) c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, addDays);
    return c;
}

static String formatTime(final Context context, int hour, int minute,
                         Alarm.DaysOfWeek daysOfWeek) {
    Calendar c = calculateAlarm(hour, minute, daysOfWeek);
    return formatTime(context, c);
}

/* used by AlarmAlert */
static String formatTime(final Context context, Calendar c) {
    String format = get24HourMode(context) ? M24 : M12;
    return (c == null) ? "" : (String)DateFormat.format(format, c);
}

/**
 * Shows day and time -- used for lock screen
 */
private static String formatDayAndTime(final Context context, Calendar c) {
    String format = get24HourMode(context) ? DM24 : DM12;
    return (c == null) ? "" : (String)DateFormat.format(format, c);
}

/**
 * Save time of the next alarm, as a formatted string, into the system
 * settings so those who care can make use of it.
 */
static void saveNextAlarm(final Context context, String timeString) {
    Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
                              Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED,
                              timeString);
}

/**
 * @return true if clock is set to 24-hour mode
 */
static boolean get24HourMode(final Context context) {
    return android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
}
```

Next:

LogCat:

```
08-05 11:42:30.222: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock$AlarmTimeAdapter.newView(AlarmClock.java:96)
```

Code:

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View ret = mFactory.inflate(R.layout.alarm_time, parent, false);

    ((TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.am)).setText(mAm);
    ((TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.pm)).setText(mPm);

    DigitalClock digitalClock =
            (DigitalClock) ret.findViewById(R.id.digitalClock);
    digitalClock.setLive(false);
    return ret;
}
```

Project: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock Apache 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mContext` in the `DigitalClock.java` class is null. you must set it a context.
add this in your class :

```
mContext=context;
```

About second problem. you must paste complete log. what is the problem?