# Android nullexception constructor

Tags: android, android-context

Hello i have a problem with the elimination of NullEx ...

I set `mContext = context` and now i have errors:

```
Implicit super constructor LinearLayout() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

public DigitalClock(Context context) {
    mContext=context;
    this(context, null);
 }
```

Earlier thread [Android alarm Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816248/android-alarm-clock) which shows problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a superclass constructor call.

```
public DigitalClock(Context context) {
    super(context); // Add a line like this.  
                   // Consult constructor documentation for correct usage.
    this(context, null); // this line must also be at the top.
    mContext=context;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are extending View, in that case you need at least two constructors.

```
//...Override Constructors...    
public DigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); 

}

public DigitalClock(Context context){
    super(context); 

}
```

See if that helps.